# Can't start any VM's in virtualbox on Windows host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Something is wrong with my VirtualBox. I had no problems of starting VM's yesterday and I have not changed anything on the host or settings on the VM's. But today when I start any of my VM's, I first get this:

[image]

If I click cancel I get:

[image]

Then I click on "Yes debug", this gives

[image]

...and the VM gets aborted. If I start it again, it loads first bootscreen but then gets stuck at black

[image]

If I click OK on the first image, the VM gets aborted directly and same thing happens when I try to start it. What can I try to do?

Comment: [Nvidia card](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=98825)? Try to disable 3D acceleration.

Comment: You should ask this question in a Windows or VirtualBox forum. I have strong doubts it has anything to do with Linux.